# Windows 11 dual boot with Ubuntu does not show boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, windows-11

I have a new Windows 11 machine in which I recently added a Ubuntu 22.04 installation as well. However the boot menu never shows up and my laptop directly starts up Windows 11. For now I am pressing F9 every time my machine starts selecting the boot manager and then starting up Ubuntu. I don't want to keep doing this on every start, instead I would like the boot menu to show up by itself and ubuntu to be the default OS.

I have tried reinstalling grub through the boot repair application in my ubuntu installation that did not work in changing bootloader to grub. In BIOS setup options I am not being allowed to change boot manager order and Windows bootloader stays above ubuntu. Tried running the command -

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Even though after I run this command it shows the operation completed successfully nothing changes upon restarting my laptop. Here is the the report from boot repair

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pZ2YKGDHh6/

Most of the previous questions are related Windows 10 or before. Trying those with Windows 11 has not worked for me. Please tell me what steps I can try following to resolve this.

Comment: Report says HP. What model? Most HP require you to change boot order in UEFI settings (not menu). HP seems to be the only vendor that does not support changing boot order with efibootmgr which grub uses to update UEFI when installing. see `man efibootmgr` for normally boot order change command. Make sure Windows fast start up is also off.

Comment: Right its HP Pavilion Plus 14-eh0021TU. Noticed fast start up was enabled by default, turned it off. Can you add a reference link to change boot order from UEFI settings for HP laptops.

Comment: I think they pretty much just say f10 into UEFI settings and go to boot and move Ubuntu to first. May need to temporarily set Secure Boot password, some systems require that for more settings. But reset or never lose that password. May be a sub-menu? hp 250 g3  Change boot order in UEFI settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467077 Needed multiple settings just to install. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555&page=2 & https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/ish_3891464-2337914-16

Comment: I feel like I have tried what you are saying. I did open up BIOS Setup options using F10. Maybe I could have written it a bit more clearly in the answer, I did get a submenu in BIOS options for windows bootloader and ubuntu. Pressing F5/F6 changed the order. However could not find a way to persist this using any key combination and had to ESC out of the submenu. Upon reopening Windows was again on top. 
 Also can you clarify what you meant by "UEFI settings (not menu)".

Comment: Settings is often f2 if boot menu is f10, but varies by vendor. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings My Dell Dell & Gigabyte Desktops use the f2 & f10. Some require UEFI password with Secure Boot on to get more settings. Never lose that password or reset to bland when done. If Secure boot is on & you installed Ubuntu with it off, system my not let you boot Ubuntu.

Comment: This solved the issue for me oldfred, if you can add this as an answer, will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report says HP. What model? Most HP require you to change boot order in UEFI settings (not menu).

Settings is often f2 if boot menu is f10, but varies by vendor.
HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings
My Dell Dell & Gigabyte Desktops use the f2 & f10.

Some require UEFI password with Secure Boot on to get more settings.
Never lose that password or reset to blank when done.

If Secure boot is on & you installed Ubuntu with it off, system my not let you boot Ubuntu.

HP PCs - Configuring the boot order in the system BIOS

https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/ish_3891464-2337914-16

Press enter to open order list:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467077

Some other settings:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555&page=2

Edit 1:

Adding that open up the bootloader submenu in BIOS setup options by pressing enter on OS Manager. In the submenu use F5/F6 to bring Ubuntu on top. Without exiting this submenu press F10 to save this order change. If you try saving after exiting the submenu, the changes in the submenu do not get saved for some reason. Once I did this the grub bootloader started coming up on startup instead of directly booting to Windows 11.