# grub-install fails at the end of ubuntu 22.04 installation on a UEFI based HP PROBOOK with preinstalled WINDOWS 11

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, uefi

I am trying to install (DUAL BOOT) UBUNTU 22.04 LTS on my UEFI based HP PROBOOK with preinstalled WINDOWS 11.

grub-install fails at the end of ubuntu 22.04 installation.

Grub install fails with NO SPACE LEFT ON DEVICE ERROR while copying " /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi"

Results of "df" command run on the terminal of live Ubuntu system :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
df: /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/: No such file or directory

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /boot/efi
ls: cannot access '/boot/efi': No such file or directory

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h /mnt/EFI/
df: /mnt/EFI/: No such file or directory

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /mnt
config-6.2.0-26-generic
initrd.img
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
efi
initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
memtest86+.bin
System.map-6.2.0-26-generic
grub
initrd.img.old
memtest86+.elf
vmlinuz
```

NOTE:

- I have allocated around 200GB of SSD space for ubuntu
- I used RUFUS to create a bootable USB drive with GPT & UEFI settings
- I created /boot partition as well
- The HP notebook is brand new
- I had disabled SECURE-BOOT, FAST-BOOT options in BIOS settings
- I ran boot-repair after the installation failed

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Sudhish

Snapshot from boot-repair paste-bin log:

```
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 efibootmgr -v before grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.


chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 uname -r
6.2.0-26-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot copy `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No space left on device.
Exit code: 1
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv winEFI cancelled (nvme0n1p1 full)

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 /sbin/grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --recheck
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/sbin/grub-install: error: cannot copy `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No space left on device.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 /sbin/grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --no-nvram
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/sbin/grub-install: error: cannot copy `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No space left on device.
--no-nvram exit code: 1 Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 efibootmgr -v after grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: It is possible that your installer tries to install that file to the drive of the live system (and not into the drive where you want it). Please boot again into the live system (booted from USB, where you used the installer) and run the following command  line: `df -h /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` and then use 'lsblk' on that device, `lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint /dev/sdx` where x is the drive letter that you found in the 'df' command. - Please edit your original question and add the commands and their output as `code` (and write a comment to indicate that it is 'done').

Comment: i guess i should have added little big chunk of the paste bin log....i will add it now.....it mentions "NVRAM Locked"....and i will run the commands you have suggested ...

Comment: I have run the `df -h /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` command on live ubuntu system. it looks like there is no efi directory with in /boot directory

Comment: You should mount the boot partition (you can get it's path with GParted or Disks) using `sudo mount [***] /mnt/` the [***] specifies where you have to insert your boot partition's path (probably starts with /dev/nvme0). And then run `df -h /mnt/EFI/`
Edit your question to contain this info.

Comment: Hey, @Octopus. I Mounted /boot partition on /mnt and executed df command on /mnt...still can not find efi directory in /mnt

Comment: Recently I installed Lubuntu Mantic on an HP Probook 640 G4 in UEFI mode alongside Windows 11. First I booted into Windows and let it shrink the Windows partition `C:` to create 100 GiB unallocated drive space (slightly less than half the drive). Then I booted into the Lubuntu live system on a USB drive and started the installer. Lubuntu uses Calamares, and it is quite easy to let it use the unallocated drive space. It will create partitions automatically and do the things smoothly. You might need to do something similar in your case, it should work with the Windows installer too.

Comment: @sudodus My notebook came with 3 partitions/drives, C(200GB), D(EMPTY 150GB) + E(EMPTY 150GB) + EFI & recovery partition. Using windows disk-management service i split D drive into 2 partitions ( 100GB NTFS + 50GB unallocated). I clubbed the 50GB unallocated partition with the (150GB  E drive) . Then i used that new 200GB partition to install UBUNTU 22.04 .  No where during the partitioning i used the SHRINK option coz generally shrink is used to get space from drive that is already been used.

Comment: @sudodus During the installation process of Ubuntu when i had to select the INSTALLATION TYPE, i chose to create or resize partition myself (3rd option) rather than installing along side Windows 11 (1st Option). when you meant "It should work with Windows installer too"..what did you mean ?

Comment: @sudodus will try your method (installation alongside Windows) and get back with the results

Comment: @sudodus Now that i have C: D: and other partitions i made to install Ubuntu, where would Ubuntu get installed if i opt to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11  (1st Option) ?

Comment: @SudhishVln, I left the drive space not used by Windows as unallocated (no partition there). Then the Lubuntu installer was successful. I think the Ubuntu installer should be successful too. But it is very important that you check carefully where the Ubuntu installer 'wants to' install (be sure to avoid overwriting Windows).

Comment: I'm guessing here, because I'm not yet really confident with the new Ubuntu installer. I know Calamares of Lubuntu and the old Ubiquity of Ubuntu (now in the 'legacy' Ubuntu Desktop iso file) better. Anyway, I think, that you must make or at least point to an existing EFI system partition when doing a manual partitioning. (You must also make or point at a big partition to become the root partition, and optionally a home partition.)

Comment: @sudodus ok...i will do it the same way then....

Comment: @sudodus- Sadly Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows boot manager also failed with the same error as before (copy error as there was No Space left on device)

Comment: @sudodus is there a way to retrieve installation logs after the installation fails ?

Comment: See post #15 HP with locked NVRam. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555&page=2 Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2 HP Pavilion Plus 14  UEFI boot order for Ubuntu with Windows 11
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464469/windows-11-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-does-not-show-boot-menu/1465075#1465075

Comment: @oldfred Will go through the links and do as instructed.....

Comment: @oldfred Apparently in my case the problem was not with NVRAM, it was the ESP that was only 100MB in size. I tried installing past versions of ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 and finally 14.04 got installed without any grub-install error but when i booted into the installed ubuntu 14,04, it gave me a warning of low /boot/efi space....which is when i realized that newer versions of ubuntu were giving grub-install error only because of low ESP OR EFI system partition space. I  increased the size of EFI system partition as described in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDa4hfGX5xE

Comment: SOLVED : and after increasing the size of ESP/EFI system partition following the procedure mentioned in the video every subsequent ubuntu installation succeeded with out any grub-install error. Thanks everyone for your support.

Comment: @SudhishVln, thanks for sharing your solution. It will be even better, if you make an 'Answer' and then, after a couple of days, you should be able to 'accept' you own answer (click the tick icon), which will make it easy for other users to find it.

Comment: @SudhishVln please don't put SOLVED on the question title on this **question answer site**. Click on the **Answer Your Own Question** button below to write your answer. Then click on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Comment: @user68186 Sure i will do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apparently in my case the problem was not with NVRAM, it was the ESP/EFI system partition that was only 100MB in size. I tried installing past versions of ubuntu.... 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 on the same system and finally 14.04 got installed without any grub-install error but when i booted into the installed ubuntu 14,04, it gave me a warning of low /boot/efi size....which is when i realized that newer versions of ubuntu were giving grub-install error only because of low ESP OR EFI system partition size[100MB by default]. I increased the size of EFI system partition as described in the following youtube video

### Increase EFI System Partiton size | MiniTool | Duaboot OS

LINK : youtube.com/watch?v=HDa4hfGX5xE

After increasing the size of ESP/EFI system partition following the procedure mentioned in the video every subsequent ubuntu installation succeeded with out any grub-install error.

---

### Suggestion for Ubuntu/GRUB guys:

I guess the following grub-install error message should have been more specific about the device/partition that was low on space. This would save lots of time and energy for the user..

````
ubuntu grub-installer: grub-install: error: cannot copy `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': No space left on device.

**This should have been something like this :**

ubuntu grub-installer: grub-install: error: cannot copy `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi': **No space left on EFI partition mounted on /boot/efi**. ```
````