# Boot Device Not Found... HP probook 4530s

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, hp

I installed the last version of Ubuntu on my hard drive by suppressing all data previously on the hard drive... Everything went fine, but when I turn on my PC, there is a BOOT DEVICE NOT found,  Hard disk (3F0) thing...
My hard drive is new and I tested, it's functioning well...
Please help me, I watched videos on YouTube, but my bios is different from their, there is no Legacy support option or whatever...
I tried anything I could, bit I am still sucked..

Comment: Many with HPs have said they have to change boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu. HP seems to be the only vendor that has an UEFI that does not work with efibootmgr which grub uses to change boot order to Ubuntu on install. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings Most vendors now do not have the old BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode which simplies things.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490046/grub-install-fails-at-the-end-of-ubuntu-22-04-installation-on-a-uefi-based-hp-pr
Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2