Problem with booting on new HP 14-ep053sa
I'm trying to install the new Ubuntu 24.04 to my new laptop, a HP 14-ep0523sa Pavilion. Unfortunately, after installation, it boots straight to a command-line interface, but not the usual one, just BusyBox. When I type 'exit', I get this error message:
BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-6ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) exit

Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID=fce50371-179c-4330-94ca-480ab3b7967b does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-6ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

It seems to install okay, and boots up to a live session with no problems. I've used all default options when installing, and I've tried reinstalling with different options a few times.
Thanks for the help, I'm usually pretty good with Ubuntu, but this one has me stumped!
edit:
Here is the result of sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 31246336 sectors, 119.2 GiB
Model: SDINFEO4-128G   
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): CA1DF70A-21DF-4619-A574-DA77EF120E94
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 256, last usable sector is 31246330
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 251 sectors (1004.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1             256          275455   1.0 GiB     EF00  
   2          275456        31246079   118.1 GiB   8300

Edit 2: weirdly, I have the same problem with Kubuntu, which uses the Calamares installers, but Debian installs without a problem. The problem appears to be Ubuntu-specific.

With HP you have to set boot order in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464469/windows-11-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-does-not-show-boot-menu/1465075#1465075 Google says UFS memory, is that a small memory card? If so you would do better with an external SSD. I upgraded desktop with newer NVMe drive and put older SSD drive in M.2 USB3 adapter. Worked so well I bought another larger NVMe drive and adapter.

Thanks for replying! Apparently it's an SSD, but what kind, I'm not sure. I'm not sure what you mean by set the boot order in UEFI, the boot order is already has OS Boot Manager as the first in the UEFI order? Thanks again!

You should see "ubuntu" as boot entry in OS Boot Manager. To confirm install  configuration: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Sure thing, I'll just do a reinstall, and then I'll install boot-repair and report back

@oldfred Here is the boot info summary https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mymz45VscD/ thanks!

@oldfred After running Boot Repair, this was the url it gave me https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2jKrQTKBRY/

Have never seen this error? "ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sdb.". PCs typically use 2048 as start, yours shows 64. Then you may have alignment issues. What brand/model system. What tools partitioned drive? What does this show. sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb assumes sda is still USB flash drive. Many systems on reboot promote flash drives or external drives to first in order. Always check if sda, sdb, etc when using a device as it may change. But UUIDs should never change.

@oldfred
The drive was partitioned by the Ubuntu 24.04 installer, and then a few times by GParted. It's a HP Pavillion, 14-ep0523sa. I've edited my post to include the results of sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb thanks again for your help

My installs of Kubuntu 24.04 use Calmares installer and to pre-partitioned drives. So have not seen a change from the standard start sector of 2048 to 256. Gdisk does not seem to complain, so may be ok. I think Mac may have been different, but not familiar with them. Have you tried typing exit at busybox line?  Sometimes it then boots.

@oldfred Sadly what I posted originally was the results of typing exit  perhaps I'll try Kubuntu, and see how that works?

Seems it cannot find the UUID fce50371-179c-4330-94ca-480ab3b7967b. Perhaps it has the wrong UUID.
I would boot into a live session from the Ubuntu media and run blkid - do you see the referenced UUID listed for the hard drive partition?
You can edit the UUID by going into grub and editing the boot parameters.
You can also check the filesystem:
sudo fsck /dev/sdb3
Or reinstall grub:
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
If that fails, maybe edit the grub config. Mount it, chroot for the mount point, and then edit the grub file:
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
nano /etc/default/grub
Change the line that says:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash root=UUID=fce50371-179c-4330-94ca-480ab3b7967b"
Save it and then run:
update-grub

I ran blkid in a live session, and I saw the referenced UUID, it's at /dev/sdb3. I'm not too sure how to go about editing grub though? Thanks!
